# Easy SQL Incorrect Syntax when using > greater than

Tags: sql, syntax, operators

This has been driving me crazy! It must be something simple.

Here is my code:

```
Select 
logid,
row_date,
sum(acdcalls) as 'total calls',
sum(ti_stafftime) as 'total time staffed',
sum(acdtime) as 'time on the phone',
Case acdtime
When acdtime > 0 Then
sum(ti_stafftime/acdtime)
Else '0'
End as MyPercent,
RepLName+', '+RepFName AS Agent,
SupLName+', '+SupFName AS Sup,
MgrLName+', '+MgrFName AS Manager
```

And I am getting the error message

> Incorrect syntax near '>'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have also tried SUM(CASE acdtime > 0 THEN (CAST(ti_stafftime as DECIMAL)/acdtime)*100 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MyPercent' and I get the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an item in the CASE portion and an expression in the WHEN. You must choose one or the other:

```
Case 
When acdtime > 0 Then sum(ti_stafftime/acdtime) 
Else '0'
End as MyPercent,
```

To use a value in the CASE portion you can do something like:

```
Case Foo
When 'Bar' Then 1
When 'Gamma' Then 2
...
End
```

However, you cannot do any complex logic in this scenario. I.e., it acts like a `switch' statement in many C-type languages by simply matching against the values in the When portions. When you want to do logic expressions, you need to keep the CASE portion blank and just have the WHEN portions.